# Cargar valor en campo personalizado ACF google map

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Tengo un CPT en wordpress que tiene un campo personalizado tipo select, que trae sus valores de una consulta a una base de datos independiente a wordpress, donde se alojan datos de eventos (fecha, direccion, horarios, etc.)
Al seleccionar un valor del desplegable, se generan nuevas consultas que devuelven valores correspondientes a un evento concreto, cuyos datos muestro en la vista del CPT. 
Ahora bien quiero precargar el valor del campo direccion que me devuelve la consulta, en otro campo del mismo CPT que otro ACF tipo GoogleMap.
Con el siguiente filtro consigo cargar el valor en el campo.

```
function acf_load_neu_events_data_value( $field ) {


    $field['value']['address'] = 'arturo soria, 2. Madrid';

    return $field;

}
```

Pero el problema es que el campo no reconoce el texto, puesto que no lo localiza en el mapa que está bajo el campo 
[image: captura-acf-wp]
como se ve no reconoce la direccion, si actualizo el post, no graba ningún valor para el campo del mapa.

Agradezco cualquier observacion.

Gracias

Comment: Quizá podrías emplear el método reload() en un jquery para actualizar el mapa en el momento que $field['value']['address'] cambie de valor.

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar a ver. Porque no he conseguido todavia solucionar el problema